# ERROR during invoking WebService - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: web-services, apache, spring, hibernate, cxf

Application: Spring + Hibernate + Apache CXF - idea simple say hello service which is taking one param - id of object in database and return text "Hello: " + person.getName();

Here are some code:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String login;

    private String email;
//getters and setters
}
```

PersonDAO:
public interface PersonDAO {
    public void savePerson(Person person);
    public Person getPerson(long id);
}

PersonDAOImpl:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void savePerson(Person person) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(person);
    }

    public Person getPerson(long id){
        Hibernate.initialize(sessionFactory);
        return (Person) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Person.class, id);
    }
}
```

PersonWebService:

```
@WebService
public interface PersonWebService {
    public String sayHello(long id);
}
```

PersonWebServiceImpl:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.robert.example.testowy.webservices.PersonWebService")
public class PersonWebServiceImpl implements PersonWebService{

    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    public String sayHello(long id) {
        Person person = personDAO.getPerson(id);
        return "Hello: " + person.getLogin();
    }

}
```

And data source conf from xml (dataSurce, sessionFactory):

```
<context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.robert.example.testowy" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edyplom"
        p:username="root"
        p:password="sedes" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <value>com.robert.example.testowy.domain</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

I have found some solutions but it does not work for me. I appreciate any help suggestions and of course solutions.

Comment: Where is the transaction started? I did not see any Transaction related annotation in PersonWebServiceImpl?

Comment: PaersonDAO is marked as ttansactional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the place where I have a mistake... WebService method in my case sayHello, should be transactional... after adding annotation @Transactional over sayHello works fine.